How to fetch a many to many relationship (with joint table)
I have a many to many relationshipt with a intermediary table:
BusinessUnit -> BusinessUnitsUsers <- Users
To fetch data from the side one I'm doing this in my find method:
buRepository.findById(id).call(e1 -> Mutiny.fetch(e1.getUsers()))

The result of this method is being enough in the endpoint that associates Users to the retrieved BU.
But I'm getting a
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: HR000056: Collection cannot be initialized error when I'm trying to remove a User from BU:
            for (Iterator<BusinessUnitsUsers> iterator = pSideOneEntity.users.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                BusinessUnitsUsers businessUnitsUsers = iterator.next();

                if (businessUnitsUsers.sideOne.equals(pSideOneEntity)
                        && Objects.equals(businessUnitsUsers.sideTwo.getId(), pUserId)) {
   Exception Here-> businessUnitsUsers.sideTwo.teams.remove(businessUnitsUsers);
                    businessUnitsUsers.sideOne = null;
                    businessUnitsUsers.sideTwo = null;
                    iterator.remove();
                    result = true;
                }
            }


What I understood is the error is being occurring because my find method is not fetching the side two of the relationship properly. businessUnitsUsers.sideTwo.teamscontains no data.
So, How can I also fetch that data in the find method above?
Btw. The code above is being migrated from a working desktop app using conventional Hibernate.
I was told that in the old context it was important to do remove the join object from both sides to keep that bi-directional relationship synchronized. But I'm wondering: it would still be necessary to do such synch in a web app since those fetched objects will gone after a request ?
